# How can I use Autoprefixer with Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, assetic, autoprefixer

I'm trying to integrate Autoprefixer in a Symfony2 (with Assetic) workflow. My first thought was that Assetic already provided support for it as a [filter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#filters) (like UglifyCSS and others), so I tried this:

```
    {% stylesheets
        '@PrivateBundle/Resources/public/less/bootstrap/bootstrap.less'
        '@PrivateBundle/Resources/public/less/private.less'

        filter='less,cssrewrite,autoprefixer,?uglifycss' 
    %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}">
    {% endstylesheets %}
```

But it didn't work.

The only alternative I could find was [netzmacht/assetic-autoprefixer](https://github.com/netzmacht/assetic-autoprefixer), but I couldn't make it work either.

I installed [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) globally (via `sudo npm install -g autoprefixer`), and also installed [kriswallsmith/assetic](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic) (which I guess is a different assetic that supports Autoprefixer) via composer, but after that I could not find the binary I need for the `parameters.yml` file.

I read on some github issue that autoprefixer may have changed several times since assetic-autoprefixer was last updated, but I can't find the thread now. There weren't any further comments about that anyway.

Is there anything I'm missing or doing wrong? Are there any other ways to use Autoprefixer (or any other similar tool) with Symfony and Assetic?

Comment: Assetic is not included in Symfony3 so it may be deprecated soon. Think about changing your workflow to gulp or webpack.

Comment: @how I know, upgrading to Symfony3 and creating a gulp workflow is a to-do, but I need to stick with Symfony2 for now.

Answer (score 4):

I finally found a solution. Seems that `autoprefixer` is no longer a standalone tool, but a plugin for other tools, so the way in which [`assetic-autoprefixer`](https://github.com/netzmacht/assetic-autoprefixer) was trying to use it (with a binary) isn't valid anymore.

So instead of `autoprefixer`, the solution was installing [`autoprefixer-cli`](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer-cli), an unofficial binary which addresses "legacy" code.

```
sudo npm install autoprefixer-cli --save
```

And then pointing to that binary in the `parameters.yml`. In my case:

```yml
assetic:
    autoprefixer:
        bin: %kernel.root_dir%/../node_modules/autoprefixer-cli/autoprefixer-cli
```

Comment: Nice! I feared I needed to use autoprefixer <= 2.2.0 (the last version having a "binary" in `.bin`).